# Function not working in c

Tags: c, function

I am learning C programming and wrote a simple program to learn function in C. I have used two functios here, although the first one works but not the second one !

Here is the simple code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
  int a,b,c,sum;
  printf("Input your numbers one by one:\n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  scanf("%d", &b);
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("You have put %d, %d, %d\n\n", a, b, c);
  max (a,b,c);
  min (a,b,c);
}

void max (int a, int b, int c) {
  int sum;
  a=sum;
  if(sum>b)
    sum=b;
  if(sum>c)
    sum=c;
}

void min (int f, int g, int h) {
  int sum;
  sum=f;
  if(sum<g)
    sum=g;
  if(sum<h)
    sum=h;
  printf("The lowest value is:%d\n\n\n",sum);
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens and the solution?

Comment: you should be careful with the uninitialized local variables in C, they are not set to zero by default.

Comment: When asking questin, you should tell what result you get, and what result you expect... Also, are you missing printf from the `max` function? As it is now, it doesn't really do anything, compiler might actually optimize it out completely...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your function should work. The first one set in the variable `a` the current value of `sum`which is unitialized.

Then when searching for the MAX value, you check if current sum (supposed to be `a`) is greater than `b` and if it is you store `b` value in `sum`.

Then if you want to call a function before it is defined you need to put the prototype of the function at the beginning of your file. As you are calling `min()` and `max()` before their definition you are having compilation errors.

It should be like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void max (int a, int b, int c);
void min (int f, int g, int h);

void main()
{
  int a,b,c,sum;
  printf("Put your numbers throughly one by one:\n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  scanf("%d", &b);
  scanf("%d", &c);
  printf("You have putted %d, %d, %d\n\n", a, b, c);
  max (a,b,c);
  min (a,b,c);
}

void max (int a, int b, int c)
{
    int sum;
    sum = a;
    if(sum<b)
        sum=b;
    if(sum<c)
        sum=c;

    printf("The max value is:%d\n\n\n",sum);
}

void min (int f, int g, int h)
{
    int sum;
    sum=f;
    if(sum>g)
        sum=g;
    if(sum>h)
        sum=h;

    printf("The min value is:%d\n\n\n",sum);
}
```

Comment: When I look at the code you gave us, max() function does not print anything (no call to printf) but min() does. In your image, max() seems to call printf() can you update your current code?

Comment: though i have update's code in Microsoft Visual Studio but it compiles me the previous code, why its not updating the new source code?

Comment: Did you save your files? Do you have some error when you build? I can see on your image that the build has just failed maybe that's it, first correct your warnings. Check my updated answer in a few seconds and try with this